# What's a good approach in creating a system of magic?

Tags: magic, balancing-magic-systems

What are the important points to consider when creating a magic-system? Particularly with curses and healing magic or white and black magic.

For example:

- Where it comes from?
- Who can wield it?
- What does society believe about it?
- What costs are there or what balances it?
- What kinds of magic are there?

Is all I have as far as questions for myself for now and that seems pretty basic. I do not need these questions answered as I am supposed to answer them. I would love more questions or different approaches to answers or links something. I do not want anyone else telling me those 5 questions are a problem and I am asking 6 questions when I am asking 1 question. I am only asking at most 3 questions( I will remove one).

I would be also really grateful for links or previous answers to some of those questions, that may help giving a direction to work with.

Comment: Hi @Echo61505, and welcome to the site!  You may want to browse the [tag:magic] tag for some of the answers you're looking for, but the site format is "specific question, answers to that question".  As it stands, your question is likely to be closed for being _way_ too broad.

Comment: The question isnt broad it just allows for plurality of answers and I did mention deliberately links to anything within or outside of this website. The questions I asked in the description are there so they can be not asked or improved or elaborated on or one can even leave options. I think it abides by site rules or hasnt reached the limits.

Comment: I suggested an edit. But I editet a lot, I hope this still fits in what you want to achieve.

Comment: and as jdunlop said, the magic tag and the balancing-magic-systems tag are a good place to start, if you can't narrow your question down. Because I'm afraid that even with my edit it still will be too broad.

Comment: I'm am browsing the magic tag now and try to find something in it

Comment: " it just allows for plurality of answers " is exactly what makes the question too broad. We prefer questions which can be answered in a measurable way. Magic itself is already pretty vague and fuzzy. If you don't narrow the scope it is getting no better.

Comment: Alright I understand.

Comment: Added some of the possible forms of magic I dont want witchcraft as it is written in the torah, book of Isaiah, Daniel, or Ezekial. I dont want the elements either. Biomanipulation and medicine would still be there but no necromancy. enchantment or sorcery.

Comment: @Echo61505 I would love to help you answer this question, as it is something i am interested in myself. I enjoy inventing original ideas for physics and magic. It would be much easier to help you if I could have a proper discussion with you, my email is andybonko3@gmail.com if your interested.

Comment: You've got mail.

Comment: You now have eight questions here. Our rules require one question / one best answer - please see the help centre about how we work: [ask] .

Comment: I wanted to remove them from being potential answers unless someone wants to give links to where people can find answers it discussions or give their own improvements or advice or chsnge the questions etc you get what I mean I mentioned this in a previous comment but I explained terribly using three words and I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

> Where it comes from?

If you want a consistent magical setting, this should be the first question to ask yourself. Is it generated by humans? Is it gained from materials (crystals, etc...) Is it an energy that's just manipulated by the wielder? Or maybe the energy of dead souls?

> What kinds of magic are there?

When you answered your first question, this should be the next one. Here it's totally up to you to define what's possible and what is not. You should by now know in which direction you're going with your magic.

> what costs are there or what balances it?

This is a trickier one. Depending on where it comes from, it availability could be limited by mana, gems, herbs, etc... If it's just manipulated energy the cost could be  that it's able to consume you or your sanity.
[This question is in a specific way asked here, I answered there with more explanation than I can provide to the vague question here.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/137509/how-can-i-balance-my-magic-to-make-it-feel-like-there-is-a-believable-cost-to-us/137616#137616)

> What does society believe?

Now you can implement your magic to a society. Ask yourself, how advanced is your society and how would people act if this kind of magic exist. It's very likely religion will form around this magic, people believeing in magical gods or demons. And lastly you should ask yourself if it is accepted by the society or feared. This highly depends on the capability and kind of magic you implement.
Those question are mostly asked around here, feel free to browse the site and find inspiration. And may ask specific questions to ONE of the points. Welcome to SEW.